# Implementing polygons with Google maps API V2 in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I implemented the Google maps API V2 on Android, I got the map to show and also the polygon to show using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Polygon polygon;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(35.20418,-90.08342);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title("My Spot")
        .snippet("This is my spot!")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
//Success! Do what you want

Log.i("service", "Google play available");
}
else{
Log.i("service", "No Google play available");
}

PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
.add(new LatLng(35.25010,-90.08342),
 new LatLng(35.25010,-90.04175),
 new LatLng(35.29177,-90.04175),
 new LatLng(35.29177,-90.08342),
 new LatLng(35.25010,-90.08342));


//Set the rectangle's stroke color to red
 rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
//Set the rectangle's fill to blue
rectOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
rectOptions.strokeWidth(2);
//Get back the mutable Polygon
polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);

}

}
```

On the Google map API V1 the `onTap` method is used to interact with the polygon. My question is what's the best way to get onTap events in version2? I've read the Google docs and unless I missed it, I did not see anything on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this  for Polygon and read this link.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon

GoogleMap map;

  Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: u can insert 4 lat lang to draw and u can also give the color of fillip the poligon......

Answer (score 0):

For now you will have to use OnMapClickListener and implement "point inside polygon" algorithm yourself (there are implementations easy to find with google).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the orientation on every 2 consecutive points of the polygon with the one that responds to the user click. This is done with checking the sign of the determinant of the matrix made from the 3 points with a third coordinate 0. Take this function for example:

```
public boolean orientation(float lat1, float lon1, float lat2, float lon2, float lat3, float lon3){
     float result = lat1*lon2 + lat2*lon3 + lat3*lon1 - lon2*lat3 - lon3*lat1 - lon1*lat2;
     if(result >= 0) return true;
     else return false;
}
```

When you call the function for all points of the polygon that form a side and all of them return the same result - the point is inside of the polygon.

Comment: The answer to this question helped me on the right path:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017892/android-check-if-my-lat-lng-position-withing-a-given-area