# How to detect that a point is inside a Polygon using Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

With the Googlemaps SDK for iOS, is it possible to detect that a point is inside a `Polygon`?

I found `containsLocation()` function in Google Maps JavaScript API, however, I couldn't find the same one in the iOS SDK.

Do you know any other ways?

Comment: there is no direct method available in google maps ios sdk . you can find if a point is inside a polygon by using mathematical calculations based on the algorithms suggested in an [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106556/get-location-address-w-r-t-the-polygon-i-am-in/19109375#19109375) . you can use the same approach in ios as well

Comment: Please file a [feature request for Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request) on our bug tracker.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Google Maps SDK for iOS now contains a function called `GMSGeometryContainsLocation`, which will help you out with a single line of code.

```
if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(yourPoint, pathOfPolygon, YES)) {
    NSLog(@"YES: you are in this polygon.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"You do not appear to be in this polygon.");
}
```

Source: [Google Maps for iOS - Reference - GMSGeometryUtils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/group___geometry_utils#ga8aad2b31a4a4197c919b8da82c84d180)

Comment: Hi @Rachid Finge Jr I have KML parser which is loaded from file by this code:
`let kmlParser = GMUKMLParser(url: url)
        kmlParser.parse()
        
        kmlParser.placemarks[0]
        let renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: self.mapView,
                                       geometries: kmlParser.placemarks,
                                       styles: kmlParser.styles)
    
        renderer.render()`
How I can check if point is in some of placemarks? 
I search for example but didn't found anything.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @DragisaDragisic di you got the solution . I am also stuck at this :)

Answer (score 2):

Converting Rachid's answer to swift was trivial:

```
if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(yourPoint, pathOfPolygon, true) {
    print("YES: you are in this polygon.")
} else {
    print("You do not appear to be in this polygon.")
}
```