# How to determine if an GMSMarker is inside of GMSPolygon (iOS Google Map SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios7

I know how to do this using Apple MapKit following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios), but don't have any idea about how to check if location or annotation (GMSMarker) is inside the GMSPolygon in Google Map SDK.

Comment: I found how to do that in Google Maps in JavaScript... from this link,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074747/check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-with-the-google-maps-api
But did not find any solution for iOS

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587792/how-to-detect-that-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-using-google-maps-sdk-for-ios.  Use GMSGeometryContainsLocation.  Even without that built-in Google method, you can use the CGPathContainsPoint approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014926/detecting-a-point-in-a-mkpolygon-broke-with-ios7-cgpathcontainspoint) to build your own CGPathRef using the coordinates of the polygon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the answer.

There is an inline function defined in GMSGeometryUtils.h file in Google SDK:

```
//Returns whether |point|,CLLocationCoordinate2D lies inside of path, GMSPath
    BOOL GMSGeometryContainsLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2D point, GMSPath *path,
                                 BOOL geodesic);
```

It contains a function called GMSGeometryContainsLocation, which determines whether location point lies inside of polygon path.

```
if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(locationPoint, polygonPath, YES)) {
    NSLog(@"locationPoint is in polygonPath.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"locationPoint is NOT in polygonPath.");
}
```

[Source: GMSGeometryContainsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/group___geometry_utils#ga8aad2b31a4a4197c919b8da82c84d180)

Comment: this one is not working for me , its crashing here if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(locationPoint, polygonPath, YES)) {

Comment: Check locationPoint and polygonPath for NULL values.

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 4** you can use this extension:

```
extension GMSPolygon {

    func contains(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {

        if self.path != nil {
            if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, self.path!, true) {
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it directly from your polygon object like this:

```
if gms_polygon.contains(coordinate: point) {
    //do stuff here
}
```