# Looking for contain(:latitude:longitude) method for GMSPath class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, path, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on bus tarcking app.I draw road of bus with GMSPath class.I need to check specific (latitude,longitude) is in that path or not.I googled,but cannot find method like contain(:latitude:longitude) for checking what I want.I also looked [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_path)
Please if you know anything about how I can do this,share your experience with me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if an GMSMarker is inside of GMSPolygon (iOS Google Map SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826631/how-to-determine-if-an-gmsmarker-is-inside-of-gmspolygon-ios-google-map-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

The bus might slightly be off path, so you might need to add some tolerance instead of strict containment. Have a look at `GMSGeometricUtils.h` and more specifically at:

```
/**
 * Returns whether |point| lies on or near |path|, within the specified |tolerance| in meters.
 * |path| is composed of great circle segments if |geodesic| is YES, and of rhumb (loxodromic)
 * segments if |geodesic| is NO.
 *
 */
BOOL GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance(CLLocationCoordinate2D point,
                                          GMSPath *path,
                                          BOOL geodesic,
                                          CLLocationDistance tolerance);
```